# Objects Randomly Flickering

Tags: 3d-view

I'm making a room with a table in Blender 2.90.1. It was working fine, until suddenly almost every object started randomly flickering in the viewport. If I don't move at all, somethings are visible and somethings aren't, and when I move or rotate in the viewport, things start turning visible or invisible. It looks fine when I render, but I can't really work on it when I can't see anything useful. Is there a way to fix this or do I have to start over?
[image]

Comment: that sounds like it might be your graphics card or driver and not your blend file...

Comment: I've never had this problem before, and I didn't make any change to the scene. This just happed on its own while I was tabbing through some Gmail pages.
Edit: There's also two object that aren't affected, the wall and the L shaped thing in the corner.

Comment: it might be a long shot but try to turn off viewport anti aliasing.
Blender preferences > viewport > quality

Also in your graphic driver, be it nvidia or amd. never never never change stuff on global settings. most of graphical issues come to games and programs because users change stuff on global settings tab. For example some games and programs might hate any change on Anisotropic filtering because of how their code work and might cause flickering on some of them.

Comment: Haven't changed any global driver settings. It wasn't anti aliasing, but your comment did lead me to the solution. Apparently if you set the clip distance low enough, it starts breaking things.